# Pulling Excel data across multiple firefox pages in Python, Selenium

Tags: excel, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, openpyxl

Goal: Take a list of First and Last names from Excel, and put them into an online registration form, using multiple firefox pages, with only one first name and one last name per page.

Tasks:

1. Open firefox page
2. Fill in "First Name" text box with Excel, cell 'A2'="Bob"
3. Fill in "Last Name" text box with Excel, cell 'B2'="Apple"
4. Click 'Submit'. -- End of Registration 1 --
5. Open a new firefox page
6. Fill in "First Name" text box with Excel, cell 'A3'="Linda"
7. Fill in "Last Name" text box with Excel, cell 'B3'= "Orange"
8. Click 'Submit'.

   ```
   for x in range(2):
       from selenium import webdriver
       browser=webdriver.Firefox()
       browser.get('The Website')
       import openpyxl
       wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Names.xlsx')
       sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Full Names')
       tuple(sheet['A2':'B3'])
       #I'm guessing about this next part:
       for rowOfCellObjects in sheet['A2':'B3']:
           for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
               browser.find_element_by_id('first_name').send_keys(????)
               browser.find_element_by_id('last_name').send_keys(????)
   ```

Using Python 3.6.2.  Excel 2016. Windows 10 x64. Selenium.
Please dumb it down in the answers, I'm very new to coding :). Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my usual format:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

headers = ['first_name', 'last_name']

data = pd.read_csv('Names.csv', names=headers) #Youll want to change the .xlsx to .csv
depth = len(data['first_names']) #this finds how deep the columns are
url = "www.website.com"
driver.get(url) #opens browser

for i in range (0,depth):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('first_name').send_keys(data['first_name'][i])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('last_name').send_keys(data['last_name'][i])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('submit').click()
```

Also note that in find_element_by_xpath, the format is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "first_name"]')
```

or similar. Youll need to ctl+i or right click-->Inspect to find the xpath.
'input' is the main tag name, and 'name' will be whatever element of 'input' has the "first_name" string literally embedded.

Comment: Hmm are you making a print() statement? If you use the depth = len(data["bill_fname"]), followed by print(depth) it should just return an integer. A way around this is if the depth of the columns is static, just set depth = some_number manually. Also, for headers = [] be sure to make the headers you place in that list to be exactly what is in the spreadsheet. Once you have those headers from the sheet, you'll need to change len(data[" "]) to whatever those headers are

Comment: Thanks! That gets it closer.  'first_name' was just my placeholder for the element id.  The element ids are ('bill_fname') #first name field, and ('bill_lname') #last name field. I subbed the first ID everywhere you had 'first_name' and the second ID where you had 'last_name'. (and used xpaths as suggested)

It returned TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len(), and it printed my entire "1" row from the csv file into the first name field.  
I was getting a KeyError when trying the plural 'bill_fnames' in the depth line and changed it to 'bill_fname' to get the above error.

Comment: I havent written print statements, no.

Comment: Try setting the depth = some_num manually for now if the len() continues to be a hold up

Comment: the csv sheet has A1=First B1=Last. 
len(data['First']) works, prints the right number!
headers=['First', 'Last']

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bill_fname"]') leads to KeyError: 'bill_fname', while the shell finds it with no problem: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bill_fname"]')
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="d8344be2-eade-4f4f-b68b-37eb1081d5dc", element="89d44047-cbb8-409e-a74b-8e38252fa4c0")>

Comment: Seeing as Pandas can read XLSX files (using the xlrd library) there is no need to convert it. However, there is no need to use Pandas here at all.